# How to create dynamic pages in Gatsby on client side

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, apollo-client

I am trying setup a blog which grabs the data from a headless WP installation. I am using Apollo/client to fetch all blog posts but would like the single blog post to be fetched CSR as well.

From my understanding `gatsby-node.js` can only do `createPages` during build time. But I'd like the single blog post to be dynamic as well e.g. `/blog/single-blog-post`.

Blog page:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client"
import Blogs from "../components/Blogs"

import Seo from "../components/seo"
import Header from "../components/Header"

const Blog = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(query)
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo title="Blog Page" />
      <Header />
      <section className="container">
        <Blogs data={data} />
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

const query = gql`
  {
    posts {
      nodes {
        slug
        title
        databaseId
        content(format: RENDERED)
        featuredImage {
          node {
            sourceUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default Blog
```

Blogs component

```
import React from "react"
import Blog from "./Blog"
export const Blogs = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <section className="section">
      <div className="section-center blogs-center">
        {data?.posts.nodes.map(blog => {
          return <Blog key={blog.databaseId} {...blog} />
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default Blogs
```

Here's the blog component

```
import React from "react"
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
const Blog = ({ databaseId, title, featuredImage, slug }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/blogs/${slug}`} key={databaseId} className="blog">
      <article>
        {featuredImage && (
          <Image
            src={featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
            style={{ width: "150px" }}
            fluid
          ></Image>
        )}
        <div className="blog-card">
          <h4>{title}</h4>
        </div>
      </article>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

I have no idea how I would setup something so that the single blog posts does not have to be rendered during build time.
I've read about client only paths but am not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> Often your application will include routes that are not known at build
> time. This includes routes that need authentication or for dynamic
> content.

To handle those pages, you can make use of the plugin client-only routes using @reach/router which is built into Gatsby.

There's also another package that you can check out: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-dynamic-routes/

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking into that, need to figure out how I'd apply that into my app. And with client-only routes I'd be able to fetch data with apollo/client I assume.